# How Do I Provide Scroll Bars When A Line Is Drawn Past Form Boundaries?

Tags: vb.net, drawing, scrollbar, drag, autoscroll

I am making a program where the form itself is a container for users to draw lines using mouse events. I would like for the form to add scroll bars (both vertical and horizontal) to the form if/when the user is drawing a line (mouse down) and drags out of the form's boundaries. Similar to when using MS Excel and dragging from cell A1 to A##, or in any direction.

Each line the user draws is an object. After Each one is drawn, I have a function that returns  the bounds of each object: `Return New Rectangle(Min(Pt1.X,Pt2.X), Min(Pt1.Y, Pt2.Y), Abs(Pt2.X-Pt1.X), Abs(Pt2.Y-Pt1.y))`. Also I have the AutoScroll property on the form set to TRUE. The form is an MDI Child, if that has anything to do with it.

The line draws on the form perfectly, but I can not get the form to add scroll bars as mentioned above. I don't have a clue as to what I should be looking into, resize event? property changes? I would really appreciate the guidance.

Comment: You have to help, it only keeps controls visible automatically, not pixels.  You must set the form's AutoScroll property to True and assign the AutoScrollMinSize property to a large enough value to keep the line visible.

Comment: Thank you Hans! I believe you are right. Even with the autoscroll property set, the form needs to know that there is a new object to account for. I think I found another post similar to this that answers my question. Again Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found that AutoScroll only enables the user to scroll to any controls placed outside of its visible boundaries. So any added objects by the user would need events to show and size the scroll bar. A question was also asked similar to this and answered with greater detail. Please visit [auto sliding of Scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215109/auto-sliding-of-scrollbars/14215392#14215392)